# Metodologia BEM + Lost Grid

Tags: html, css, html5, sass, bem

Eu gostaria de saber qual seria a melhor pratica para usar diferentes tamanhos de grid com o mesmo block.

Ex:

- Eu tenho um componente *Card*, e na minha página de dashboard eu desejo que tenha 4 *Card*s por linha
- Também utilizo este componente em outros lugares, na página de usuários, eu desejo exibir 2 cards por linha

No caso eu teria:

```
// dashboard.html

| Card1 | Card2 | Card3 | Card4 |
| Card5 | Card6 | Card7 | Card8 |

// users.html

|     Card1     |     Card2     |
|     Card3     |     Card4     |


// Estrutura

<div class="Card">
    <div class="Card__title">
        Meu titulo
    </div>
    <div class="Card__content">
        Meu conteúdo
    </div>
</div>
```

Eu pensei nas seguintes opções:

```
// Card.scss

.Card {
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.Card__title {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

1. Criar um componentes customizado para cada página

```
// Dash-cardgrid.scss

.Dash-cardgrid {
    > .Card {
            lost-column: 1/4;
    }
}

// User-cardgrid.scss

.User-cardgrid {
    > .Card {
            lost-column: 1/2;
    }
}
```

2. Criar um componente para cada página

```
// Dash-card.scss

.Dash-card{
    @extend .Card;
    lost-column: 1/4;
}

// User-card.scss

.User-card{
    @extend .Card;
    lost-column: 1/2;   
}
```

3. Criar modifiers

```
// Card.scss

.Card {
    ...
    &--four-by-row {
        lost-column: 1/4;   
    }

    &--two-by-row {
        lost-column: 1/2;   
    }
}
...
```

4. Criar um utilitário de gris

```
// utils.scss

.utils {
    ...
    &--four-by-row {
        lost-column: 1/4;   
    }

    &--two-by-row {
        lost-column: 1/2;   
    }
}
...
```

5. Utilizar mesmo alguma grid de algum framework (mas o objetivo era para deixar o html mais limpo e simples de se entender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta neste artigo:

http://webuild.envato.com/blog/how-to-scale-and-maintain-legacy-css-with-sass-and-smacss/

Basicamente, eu irei criar os componentes normalmente, e caso eu precise trabalhar com a grid em um local específico, eu posso criar um módulo da parte da aplicação que eu estiver trabalhando e sobreescrever o componente

```
<div class="my-module">
  <div class="my-module__child-component">
    <div class="child-component">
      <div class="child-component__grandchild-component">
        <div class="grandchild-component--modifier"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```